# PowerApps - Creating Survey & Answer with Radio Button

Tags: powerapps, survey, powerapps-canvas

I'm creating a PowerApps that can retrieve Quiz & Answer from SharePoint List, but I want to minimise the maintenance from Developer, means when user want to create new course, they just need to submit their Quiz & Answer (multiple choice), and then it will display in powerapps's exam screen template. But I'm not sure how to make it works, any suggestion? I dont want to editing the Powerapps everytime user submit new course.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

your question seems generic and you need opinion on how to tackle architecture/technological level.

You already have question and answers into your SharePoint, I think you already have your PowerApps created which fetches all the question and answers.

So you might have gallery which will show each and every record from your question and answer. you might have Edit/detail screen which will show you all the details of every row/that is question and answer.

So any new question and answer record should be visible under your gallery and you can easily view it. There will not be a need to perform any changes to your app if you have set it up as per your need.